# Cast byte array to Json using Fuel and Result

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I want to get my response body in a JSON Object using Fuel and Result.
This is my callback code :

```
private fun LoginCallback(result: Result<Any, Exception>?)
{
    mAuthTask = null
    showProgress(false)
    val (data, error) = result ?: return (Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
            R.string.error_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show())

    result.success {
        val dataJson = data as Json
        val user: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SAVED_USER_INFOS, 0)
        val editor = user.edit()
        editor.putString(SAVED_ACCESS_TOKEN, dataJson.obj().getString(SAVED_ACCESS_TOKEN))
        editor.putString(SAVED_TOKEN_LIFETIME, dataJson.obj().getString(SAVED_TOKEN_LIFETIME))
        editor.apply()
        finish()
        startActivity<MainActivity>()
    }
    result.failure {
        showProgress(false)
        mPasswordView!!.error = getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password)
        mPasswordView!!.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

But when I try to cast my data (byte array) to Json I have this error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: byte[] cannot be cast to com.github.kittinunf.fuel.android.core.Json
```

Any idea where this can come from? The code was working before I changed to another API route.

I verified that a JSON string is stored in data.

And the API response seems to be valid.

```
                                                        Response : OK
                                                        Length : 220
                                                        Body : {"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OWVlZDU4NzIxMjcwMzc2MDUwZmY2MjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1MDkxNzcds0MjgsImV4cCI6MTU5NTU3NzQyOH0.VwAkLeKW2SL3bMDhQIs-0Pwx0kMg9xgzpDLxprbCUvQ","tokenExpirationDate":1509263828796}
                                                        Headers : (13)
                                                        null : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
                                                        Connection : [Keep-Alive]
                                                        Content-Length : [220]
                                                        Content-Type : [application/json; charset=utf-8]
                                                        Date : [Sat, 28 Oct 2017 07:57:08 GMT]
                                                        ETag : [W/"dc-SzYVR7bdKvnAvN0IajN0NVs3SIE"]
                                                        Keep-Alive : [timeout=5, max=100]
                                                        Server : [Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)]
                                                        X-Android-Received-Millis : [1509177392976]
                                                        X-Android-Response-Source : [NETWORK 200]
                                                        X-Android-Selected-Protocol : [http/1.1]
                                                        X-Android-Sent-Millis : [1509177392520]
                                                        X-Powered-By : [Express]
```

Got any idea of what could have gone wrong?

Comment: byte[] isn't a subtype of Json. because of that you are getting the exception. You should construct your Json with thos bytes (or passing a string contructed with the bytes)

Comment: It looks that you can return the proper String/Json/ object using [Result](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel#result)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

data is of `byte []` - byte array. You cannot cast it to Json.

```
val dataJson  = Json(String(data))
```

Above is the right way to do.
`String(data)` will convert `byte array` data to `String`.